# How to change color in Kolourpaint?

Tags: graphics, kubuntu, kde, kolourpaint

[image]

There isn't any toolbar to change line/pencil color.
How to add the toolbar?

I have installed Kolourpaint from default Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click the Menubar (File Edit View ...) and enable the "Color Box"

[image]