# How do I get back the colours toolbar in Kolour Paint?

Tags: graphics, kubuntu, kde

I have accidentally removed the colours toolbar on Kolour paint.
I have [tried right clicking](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95722/how-to-change-color-in-kolourpaint) on the menu bar but the toolbar settings options shows up disabled.

Answer (score 6):

The KolourPaint is a KDE application: http://www.kolourpaint.org/.

The KDE applications are saving the settings to the `~/.kde/share/config/`. That is: `/home/UserName/.kde/share/config/`.

Resetting to the defaults:

1. Rename or remove the `~/.kde/share/config/kolourpaintrc` file, when the KolourPaint is not running.
2. Next time the KolourPaint will start with the default settings with the "Color Box".

Comment: The path is ~/.config/kolourpaintrc in my computer.

Comment: ~/.var/app/org.kde.kolourpaint/config/kolourpaintrc on my computer... Using kolourpaint from a flatpak.

Answer (score 0):

I used FSearch to search for `kolourpaint`. In the *Path* column, I looked for `.config`. In the *Name* column next to it, I deleted `kolourpaintrc`. My color palette came back.